# 'invalid for creating a default constraint' error when trying to add a constraint to an existing table

Tags: sql, sql-server, constraints, alter-table

I want to add a default constraint using `ALTER TABLE` in SQL Server, but I received the below error message instead.

> Column 'StartDate' in table 'Register' is invalid for creating a
>   default constraint.

I know that I can declare a constraint when I create a table, but that isn't the situation I am in. I hope someone can help me ;)

Here is my `alter` statement:

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Register]
  ADD CONSTRAINT [Register_StartDate] DEFAULT (GETDATE()) FOR StartDate
```

And this is my create table script:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Register]
  (
     [ID]        [INT] IDENTITY(1, 1) NOT NULL,
     /* ....*/
     [StartDate] [DATETIME] NULL
  )
```

**Edited: Fixed: I forgot that the [StartDate] field doesn't even exist in the table. My bad!**

Comment: It is working fine for me.

Comment: Can't reproduce - there must be something else going on. Are you (a) in the right database, (b) sure that your `Register` table is really created like this, and (c) that `StartDate` is really `DATETIME` in that table??

Comment: Have you tried adding the default constraint while creating the column? does that work?

Comment: I just figured that I don't even create the column name in the table. Thank you, guys!

Comment: This was helpful to me, but it should be formatted in a Q&A format, see the FAQ.

Comment: Even though the eventual solution here is added to the question I added an answer to get it off the unanswered questions list. Also there is another potential explanation for future Googlers.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As far as I'm aware there are two possible circumstances that might cause this error.

Attempting to add a default constraint to:

1. A computed column.
2. A column that doesn't exist at all!

For the table definition

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Register
  (
     ID INT IDENTITY(1, 1) NOT NULL,
     Computed AS 'Foo'
  )
```

Both of the following statements fail with error 1752.

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.Register
  ADD CONSTRAINT C1 DEFAULT 'X' FOR Computed

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Register]
  ADD CONSTRAINT [Register_StartDate] DEFAULT (GETDATE()) FOR StartDate
```

There are [various other conditions](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191289%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) on which it is not permissible to add a default constraint to a column but these all have their own unique error numbers and messages.

```
+------------------------------------+--------------+
|               Reason               | Error number |
+------------------------------------+--------------+
| Column is IDENTITY                 |         1754 |
| Column is timestamp/rowversion     |         1755 |
| Sparse Column                      |         1791 |
| Default constraint already present |         1781 |
+------------------------------------+--------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

Error 1752 suggests that column name referenced in the constraint definition does not exist.
Cross check if column exists in the table or if we are referencing incorrect name in default constraint definition.